# How to programatically map signals, run simulation and get outport results Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Here is my problem :

I have a simulink component with multiple inports.

I have a code which generate sequences according to inport type and save them into a mat file. Sequences are timetable or timeseries.

I want to make my code more generic. I want my code to map signals according to names (sequence names are the same as inport block names), run the simulation and get results of the simulation to plot them later.

I made a lot of research but I don't understand how to do it.

Here is what I understand of my research :

Simulink.SimulationInput allows me to change some variable of my simulink model

GetSlRootInportMap allows me to map each signals to inport block according to their names (I have a field in a structure which contains all inport block name)

sim (or parsim, I don't know which one use in my case) allows me to run a simulation and get simulation results.

What I don't understand is in which order I should use all of theses functions, how to arrange them together to have what I want. I am a bit lost in all these functions.

To sum up, my main objective is to made my tests of simulink model automatic. I already did a first step by generate sequences according to inport type and I want to go further by automatise simulink test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following framework for programmatically running several simulations:

```
for n = 1:numTests
 simIn(n) = Simulink.SimulationInput('modelName'); % create Simulation input object
 % Modify simIn(n) to have the desired inputs, (see link "SimulationInput objects" below)
 simIn(n) = setExternalInput(simIn(n), inVals); % for example
end

simOut = sim(simIn); % simulates all Simulation Input objects, one at a time
% simOut = parsim(simIn); % this would simulate in parallel, recommended if there are a LOT of tests

for n = 1:numTests
 % post process results from simOut(n)
end
```

[SimulationInput objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationinput.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I didn't explain correctly my problem. What I want to do is to run one simulation in which my simulink object has for example 30 inports blocks. What I want to do is to match my data to all inports blocks and then run my simulation to get outport results. But thank you for your answer, it helped me to understand how to structure my code